# C# qualified import

Tags: c#

In Haskell, I can do something like this:

```
import qualified AST as A
```

Then I can use it like:

```
transProg :: Prog -> A.M_stmt
```

The AST.hs contains the AST for a grammar:

```
module AST where

data M_stmt = M_ass (String,[M_expr],M_expr)
             | M_while (M_expr,M_stmt)
```

etc...

How can I do the same thing in C#? What would be my AST.hs look like? How do I do qualified import into another C# file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `using A = Ast` - [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

a direct translation of your `M_stmt` is a bit more involved - usually you convert `M_stmt` into a (abstract) base class and have the `M_ass`, etc. into derived classes of this.

I'm sure you can do it yourself

Comment: can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231040/parser-in-c-sharp-and-printing-ast please?